# IIS Authentication in VS Angular project

Tags: angularjs

So, what is the best technique to use windows integrated security in an angular application?   In VS Studio, I'd just use Razor/CSHTML to get what I'm trying to do,  now I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing with Anulgar.

Among other things, I'd want to capture the current user logged in, I figure IIS integrated would have the authentication parts.

It's not really sophisticated in that I'm trying to make decisions of what needs to happen, in the sense that I'm not having to worry about group membership or anything like that at this time.

Thanks!

Comment: I would use Token authentication or Cookie based authentication. I would say most use a token service, to keep an active token while using the application, which involves storing the token string in either a cookie or session/local storage.

Comment: I think what I'm trying to do I can't yet.   That'd be something akin to single sign on....  :(